# Visual collaborative platform to plan a book

Tags: plot, structure, tools, resources, planning

I have searched and found some tools for writing, but I need a platform to be able to plan a book - can anyone point me in the right direction? This is for a group of people who want to plan and create the ultimate reading experience. We have tried other options like Google Docs and directory structure in other Cloud storage apps, but we need more of a visual tool that will allow us to look at timelines both in story and planning, etc.

The ultimate solution would have a structure, for example:

(topic, character traits) > suggestion > voting > assignment > closed/adapted.

Visual is one key point here.

Comment: The Ultimate reading experience? Not a low bar. Gantt charts are used for project management of large teams solving complex problems. Googling the term will show you lots of software solutions. They are not typically used for plotting a novel, but I can't think of any reason why they couldn't be.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am sure you will agree with the statement "The Ultimate reading experience" when I will reveal the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **[Miro](https://miro.com/).**

You can create multiple boards to plan various aspects. We have been using Miro for almost a year now in software development. But this tool should work well for many other purposes. Below is a screenshot with some templates for a new board, which should give you a rough idea how this can look. But there are many more possiblities.

However the tool is more focused on planning things. Not sure if this works well to manage and bring together various texts or discuss drafts. At least you can link visual elements in Miro to anything in the web, for example a space where texts are stored.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Matt, I will have a look, it looks good, and it could be a start for the planning stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Mural](https://www.mural.co/), it has many visual features and a nice collaborative environment.

If you want a less visual option but also with lots of collaborative tools and integrations, you could also try [Trello](https://trello.com/)

Comment: That's two answers.  You should post them separately so that they may be voted upon separately.